# Isomorphism between the real plane and a set of functions

Tags: group-theory

I have been told that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to the collection of functions $2\to\mathbb{R}$. Does this statement make sense at all? And if yes, how does this isomorphism work?

Thanks

Comment: Take a vector $(x_1,x_2)$. This defines a function mapping $0$ to $x_1$ and mapping $1$ to $x_2$. Conversely, every function $f:\{0,1\}\to \Bbb R$ gives a vector $(f(0),f(1))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is sensible. Here, $\textbf{2}:=\{0,1\}.$

Every element of $\Bbb R^2$ is an ordered pair whose first and second components are both members of $\Bbb R$. Every element of ${}^{\textbf{2}}\Bbb R$ (one notation for the set of functions $\textbf{2}\to\Bbb R$) is a function taking the first element and second element of $\textbf{2}$ to elements of $\Bbb R$. Does this suggest to you how the natural bijection can be constructed?

As for *isomorphic*, you should be able to show that ${}^{\textbf{2}}\Bbb R$ is a group under the operation $\oplus$ given by $$(f\oplus g)(x):=f(x)+g(x).$$ The natural bijection will be operation-preserving, and so will be the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Although the question should have said so, the (group-theory) tag suggests that a group isomorphism is intended.  I don't know if the tag was added before or after you answered the equation.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for pointing that out. I really should have noticed that.